# Continious shooting bracketing on a Nikon D7500

Tags: nikon, bracketing

With my old D80, if you set up bracketing and held down the button, it would shoot the bracketed shots as fast as it could, and then stop.

I can find no setting on my D7500 that produces this same behavior.  It either fires the shots one at a time or doesn't stop when the bracketing is done.  On continuous/slow, I can almost always count it correctly, but not every time.

Am I missing something, or isn't this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to automatically shoot the correct number of shots as per your old D80.

I have a D7500 and have been regularly been shooting scenes using bracketing, and it shoots the complete set of images and then stops.

A typical bracketing solution for me is:

- Hold down the BKT button, and use the "Main command dial" (rear dial)
  to select the number of shots.  Also use the "sub command dial"
  (front dial) to select the EV separation. (Currently I am using
  5F/1.0 to shoot 5 shots that are -2, -1, 0, +1, +2 EVs around my base
  exposure)
- Select either C<sub>L</sub> or C<sub>H</sub> on the "Release mode
  dial". (I am normally using C<sub>L</sub> for my subjects)

Doing that is all that I need to do to shoot the desired number of shots when I hold down the shutter release.

Could you have modified other bracketing settings in the Custom menu like the d1 CL mode shooting speed, or the d2 Max continuous release? etc.  I'd recommend doing a factory reset on your camera and setting up bracketing again.

Finally, if you don't firmly hold down the shutter release during a bracketing sequence then the camera will stop taking that sequence.  That actually happened to me this morning.